# Reset Databinding automatically in winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, binding

As all of us know, if we want to bind a control in the WinForm to a property It has to be done through the fallowing way:

```
txtTitle.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", object, "Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
```

but in this case if "object" ( second argument of the Binding) changes to another one, in order to reflect change in the UI, we have to reset binding in this way:

```
txtTitle.DataBindings.Clear();
txtTitle.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", object, "Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
```

but I'm looking for a solution that does the above code snippet automatically, without the need to do it manually.
I think BindingSource might help me because it has ResetBinding() method but I'm not sure.
I'll appreciate your guides.
Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
I know how to update UI element after changing property value by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface, but my question is how to deal with the situation when my **object** that UI control is bound to its property changes, **not** the **property** itself.

.
.
.
consider this situation. I have a list of objects of a class and I want to bind my textbox to the property of this class, but based on some situations I want to change my object that is selected from that list so textbox has to be updated to reflect the new object's property value. at the current stage the only solution I can use is to delete previous binding and add new one. I want that somehow UI element be aware of the situation and shows new object's property value automatically or with smallest code as possible.

Comment: ...and we appreciate *your* [guids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Comment: why you need it? i believe on main data source object there must be a refresh method that will refresh all bind objects

Comment: @sairfan because when my form loads, it is ok and everything looks good but after changing my binding source object to something else, changes no longer be reflected on UI until I reset it manually somehow. I think there would be a more efficient way rather than this one.

Comment: I don't that is a good approach that you change your binding source, rather can you update data to data source?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to update bound controls when changing the datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941537/better-way-to-update-bound-controls-when-changing-the-datasource)

Comment: @sairfan I added some edit to my question to clarify my intend.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm really not understanding your use-case, all you need is a `BindingSource` object between your `TextBox` and data object.

You don't bind your TextBox directly to your object, but to the BindingSource. All you have to do is use the `DataSource` and `DataMember` properties of the BindingSource to "switch" which object is used as the source of data for your controls.

See: [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In order to clarify my Q: Consider that I have a class that has a string property called NAME. now I have also a list of objects of this class. first I bind my textbox to NAME property of one of the members of this list. everything is fine but based on some conditions, I decide to change my source object and use another object of the list and its NAME property. because TextBox source object has changed the TextBox won't be updated until I clear my previous binding and add new one. I'm wondering is there any easy automated way without the need of resetting it manually?

Comment: Again, you don't want to bind the TextBox directly to the object/list, you bind it to the BindingSource. You can then set the DataSource on the BindingSource to update displayed values to those of the newly bound object.